# Creating writing and reading from buffer wgpu

Tags: rust, webgpu, wgpu-rs

I have just recently started learning about how to compute on a GPU and I have decided to start with WGPU as I'm familiar with rust and it can be run on pretty much every GPU. As far as my current understanding goes first I have to create a buffer that is accessible to my CPU, which I have done with the following code.

```rust
    let array_buffer = device.create_buffer(&wgpu::BufferDescriptor{
        label: Some("gpu_test"),
        size: (arr.len() * std::mem::size_of::<[i32; 5]>()) as u64,
        usage: wgpu::BufferUsages::COPY_DST | wgpu::BufferUsages::MAP_READ,
        mapped_at_creation: false,
    });
```

After that I have wrote some random data to this buffer with the following line.

```rust
queue.write_buffer(&array_buffer, 0, &[1,2,3,4]);
```

As of right now I have no errors but the problem appears when I now want to read the data in this buffer, there is no example of how to read the data off a buffer in wgpu docs and I didn't see one in webGPU docs too.

In addition how do I know if the buffer is accessible on CPU or GPU webGPU docs talk about it but they don't have an explicate example of how to define a buffer for each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, in order to be able to read a buffer, it must have `BufferUsages::MAP_READ`. You've already done that. If you wanted to read a buffer that can't have that usage, you'd need to copy data to a temporary buffer first.

Given that prerequisite, the steps are:

1. Call `BufferView::map_async()`
2. Call `Device::poll()`
3. Confirm that the `map_async()` callback has been called with a successful `Result`
4. Call `BufferView::get_mapped_range()`

Here's the code I've used for that, which maps the buffer in the variable `temp_buffer`:

```rust
let (sender, receiver) = futures_channel::oneshot::channel();
temp_buffer
    .slice(..)
    .map_async(wgpu::MapMode::Read, |result| {
        let _ = sender.send(result);
    });
device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::Wait); // TODO: poll in the background instead of blocking
receiver
    .await
    .expect("communication failed")
    .expect("buffer reading failed");
let slice: &[u8] = &temp_buffer.slice(..).get_mapped_range();
```

Note that as per the TODO, this particular code is a work in progress halfway between two sensible states:

- If you intend only to block on the buffer being ready to read, then you don't need a `channel`, just a [`OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html) because the message will always have arrived when `poll(Maintain::Wait)` returns.
- If you want to be truly async, then something needs to be calling either [`poll(Maintain::Poll)`](https://docs.rs/wgpu/latest/wgpu/struct.Device.html#method.poll) or `Queue::submit()` repeatedly in the background to trigger checking for completion and thus the callback.

Comment: So I have done what you said and I do get an output now, but it is all 0 I'm going to update the post with new code if you don't mind tell me what I have done wrong.

Comment: @LAYTOR Sorry, I don't see any problems in that small snippet. It's not good to change what your question is after it's been answered — I get that you want a working solution, but the question was “how is this done”, not “spot the bug in…”. Please consider constructing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and posting it as a new question.

Comment: Thank you, I will create a new question it is just that I had wanted to get an answer which could be used as reference by people who are new to shaders and have decides to start learning wgpu first. As docs don't really talk about buffers I made this post on creating writhing and reading off the buffer. It is just that I hadn't realized that there was another bug in my code relating to a write operation, but just how you advised I will ask about it in a new post thank you for resolving my problem with reading from the buffer you saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score -1):

WebGPU's API is cross-platform. So I will give you a solution from Javascript WebGPU.

A canon alternative to Kevin's approach is `(GPU)CommandEncoder.copy_buffer_to_buffer()` / `copyBufferToBuffer()`. This [is described in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GPUCommandEncoder/copyBufferToBuffer), which I paraphrase and embellish:

```
// Create an output buffer to read GPU calculations to, and a 
// staging buffer to be mapped for CPU (JavaScript, Rust) access.
const gpuBuffer = device.createBuffer({
  size: BUFFER_SIZE,
  usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_SRC,
});

const cpuReadableBuffer = device.createBuffer({
  size: BUFFER_SIZE,
  usage: GPUBufferUsage.MAP_READ | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
});

// ...

// Create GPUCommandEncoder to encode commands to issue to the GPU.
const commandEncoder = device.createCommandEncoder();

// ...your compute dispatches...

// Copy output buffer to staging buffer.
commandEncoder.copyBufferToBuffer(
  gpuBuffer,
  0, // Source offset
  cpuReadableBuffer,
  0, // Destination offset
  BUFFER_SIZE,
);

// ...vertex and fragment shader dispatches...

// Send all commands off to the GPU for execution.
device.queue.submit([commandEncoder.finish()]);

// Finally, map and read from the CPU-readable buffer.
cpuDebugBuffer.mapAsync
(
    GPUMapMode.READ,
    0, // Offset
    debugBufferSize // Length
).then( () => { //resolves the Promise created by the call to mapAsync()
    const copyArrayBuffer = cpuDebugBuffer.getMappedRange(0, debugBufferSize);
    const data = copyArrayBuffer.slice();
    cpuDebugBuffer.unmap();

    console.log(new Float32Array(data)); //display the information.
});
```

I added the last parts so you can see the full workflow (lacking in MDN docs). Naturally, your `(GPU)BindGroup`s and `(GPU)BindGroupLayout`s will need to match the buffers created, as will your compute shader's bindings.